# How to properly escape PHP $_POST variables from AJAX form?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I created an AJAX submission form using jQuery and processing the form mailer with PHP (which is what you see below.) Based on the below code, what's the best way to escape the superglobal $_POST variable from content received fromt the AJAX/jQuery form? Is it okay to wrap the trim() function in a htmlspecialchars() function? What type of security do I have to be concerned with when sending a php mailer as the contents of the email aren't being inserted in to the database.

```
<?php

    $content_link = trim($_POST['content_link']);
    $email = trim($_POST['email']);
    $viewport_size = trim($_POST['viewportsize']);
    $browser = trim($_POST['browser']);
    $os = trim($_POST['os']);
    $current_page = trim($_POST['current_page']);

    $to = '<example@example.com>';      
    $from = '<' . $email . '>';
    $subject = 'Form Submission';   
    $message = '
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head></head>
    <body>
    <table>
        <tr><td>Content Link:</td><td>' . nl2br($content_link) . '</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Email:</td><td>' . $email . '</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Viewport Size:</td><td>' . $viewport_size . '</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Browser/OS:</td><td>' . $browser . '/' . $os . '</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Current Page:</td><td>' . $current_page . '</td></tr>
    </table>
    </body>
    </html>';

    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'From: ' . $from . "\r\n";

    mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
```

Comment: htmlentites($value) for echoing any data to prevent people submitting javascript etc..

Comment: You need to do some work in preventing [email injection](http://www.securephpwiki.com/index.php/Email_Injection).

Answer (score 0):

You could simply wrap the htmlentities function around the variables since you are not doing any database calls.  Also you can simplify assigning variables to the post by just using the extract function

```
<?php

    extract($_POST);

    $to = '<example@example.com>';      
    $from = '<' . $email . '>';
    $subject = 'Form Submission';   
    $message = '
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head></head>
    <body>
    <table>
        <tr><td>Content Link:</td><td>' . nl2br(htmlentities(trim($content_link))) . '</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Email:</td><td>' . htmlentities(trim($email)) . '</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Viewport Size:</td><td>' . htmlentities(trim($viewportsize)) . '</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Browser/OS:</td><td>' . htmlentities(trim($browser)) . '/' . htmlentities(trim($os)) . '</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Current Page:</td><td>' . htmlentities(trim($current_page)) . '</td></tr>
    </table>
    </body>
    </html>';

    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'From: ' . $from . "\r\n";

    mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
```

Comment: wouldn't I also need to escape the $email on the line where it says: $from = '<' . $email . '>';

Answer (score 0):

You can also use  strip_tags() function if you want to strip all input of HTML entities.

[strip_tags() Example](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php)

Answer (score 0):

Use regular expresions on the feilds it's one way to go, another is to use  `filter_var('bob@example.com', FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)` you can pass a lot of flags to the filter_var($_POST['content'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING) there is plenty of filters so take a look at the docs, take special attention to the email because someone could inject CC BCC. htmlentities, htmlcharacters, i mean there is a lot of ways to get this done i'll probably use regex or filter_var.

Comment: Will htmlentities or htmlcharacters protect me form an email injection?